# Different Button Actions for each Segmented Control Segment

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I have a button that I would like to perform different code when each of 3 segmented controls are selected. EX) If segment1 is selected, Code1 will be executed when theButton is pressed. If segment2 is selected, Code2 will be executed when theButton is pressed. I haven't worked with Segmented Controls before, anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have target action setup on your button and an IBOutlet to your segmented control you could do the following.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender
 {
    NSInteger selectedIndex = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    switch(selectedIndex)
    {
       case 1: [self methodOne]; break;
       case 2: [self methodTwo]; break;
       case 3: [self methodThree]; break;
       default : break; //Do nothing
    }
 }
```

Comment: It's a pity there's apparently no way to do this from IB or Storyboard file. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Just do in a very simply way :-
If you have taken the outlet of segmentcontrol then do it like that below:-

```
         NSInteger sel=[yourSegmentCntrl       
         selectedSegment];
      If (sel==1)
       {
       //write your code
         }
```

Comment: Like tht way you can check your condition accordingly

Comment: Does Objective-C have the Javascript equivalent of a switch statement? I think that would be most effective. Otherwise, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: Yes defintely, it has switch case:) the above sample is just for ease understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Since I was working on this recently I thought I'd add another answer that could help Swift guys out with the transition to Obj-C. This is a bit more explicit and matches something we'd see in Swift with IBOutlets.

```
- (IBAction)segmentedControlAction:(id)sender {

// This property can be a simple primitive. No need for an NSObject like NSInteger.
int selectedIndex = self.segmentedControlOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex;

switch(selectedIndex)
{
    // Simply changing output to label
    case 0: self.label.text = @"Segment 1 was selected";
        break;
    case 1: self.label.text = @"Segment 2 was selected";
        break;
    case 2: self.label.text = @"Segment 3 was selected";
        break;
    case 3: self.label.text = @"Segment 4 was selected";
        break;

    default : break; //Do nothing
}
```

}